# Search functionality only uses one parameter

Tags: php, laravel, search, eloquent

:)

I have implemented a search functionality for users who want to browse job postings, it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGcW6.png

The code for it looks like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
if ($word = $request->get('s')) {

                $postsQuery = $postsQuery
                    ->where('titel', 'like', "%{$word}%")
                    ->where('isActive', 1)
                    ->where('is_Canceled', 0)
                    ->orWhere('id', '=', $word);

            }

            if ($location = $request->get('standort') and $request->get('standort') != 'alle') {
                $postsQuery = $postsQuery->where('Standort', $location);
            }

            if ($dep = $request->get('abteilung') and $request->get('abteilung') != 'alle') {
                $postsQuery = $postsQuery->where('abteilung_name', $dep);
            }

            $posts = $postsQuery->orderBy('titel')->get();

            if ($posts->count() == 0) {

                return view('posts.overview', ['posts' => $posts, 'standorts' => $standorts, 'abteilungs' => $abteilungs])
                    ->withErrors(['error' => 'Es wurde kein Treffer gefunden, versuchen Sie es mit anderen Suchparametern']);
            }

            return view('posts.overview', ['posts' => $posts, 'standorts' => $standorts, 'abteilungs' => $abteilungs]);
        }
```

My issue is that only one parameter gets searched for. So when a user enters a search term "IT" + a location (Standort) or a department (Abteilung) only the search term is searched for.

I tried countless different things for 2 hours but I just cant get it to work. If you have any tipps let me know!

EDIT: when I leave out the `orWhere('id', '=', $word)` it works, but I have to leave it in. But I cant change it to normal `where()` because then it returns no matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did:

`where a and b and c or d`

But you want:

`where (a and b and c) or d`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping

So roughly, you should strive to build something like this:

```php
$posts = Post::query()
    ->where(function (Builder $query) {
        $query->where('clauseA', '=', 1)
            ->where('clauseB', '=', 2)
            ->where('clauseC', '=', 3);
    })
    ->orWhere('id', '=', $word)
    ->get();
```

Comment: yes !! I don't know how delusional I am or if I am becoming blind. I fixed it now in another way, should I post the answer? I was told few weeks ago that another question was too specific so I shouldn't post the answer. Is this one too specific as well?

Comment: share it, why not :)

Comment: yeah you are right. I just got downvoted hard the last time I did it.

Comment: are you still here? I would have a question about your solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
if ($word = $request->get('s')) {

                if (is_numeric($word)) {
                    $postsQuery = $postsQuery
                        ->where('id', '=', $word)
                        ->where('isActive', 1)
                        ->where('is_Canceled', 0);

                }  else {
                    $postsQuery = $postsQuery
                        ->where('titel', 'like', "%{$word}%")
                        ->where('isActive', 1)
                        ->where('is_Canceled', 0);
                }

            }

            if ($location = $request->get('standort') and $request->get('standort') != 'alle') {
                $postsQuery = $postsQuery->where('Standort', $location);
            }

            if ($dep = $request->get('abteilung') and $request->get('abteilung') != 'alle') {
                $postsQuery = $postsQuery->where('abteilung_name', $dep);
            }

            $posts = $postsQuery->orderBy('titel')->get();

            if ($posts->count() == 0) {

                return view('posts.overview', ['posts' => $posts, 'standorts' => $standorts, 'abteilungs' => $abteilungs])
                    ->withErrors(['error' => 'Es wurde kein Treffer gefunden, versuchen Sie es mit anderen Suchparametern']);
            }

            return view('posts.overview', ['posts' => $posts, 'standorts' => $standorts, 'abteilungs' => $abteilungs]);
        }
```

It is not an elegant solution but I just check if the search-term is a number or a word and then proceeds to the according condition and search function

Comment: Yeah, that's a almost a different question, but I see your idea.
I'd probably do a couple of functions:
`searchById()`
`searchByKeyword()` and both functions would reuse the common logic extracted to the third one `buildSearchQuery()`

Comment: Or, maybe this could help as well:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Comment: @AndriusRimkus yeah it is complete spaghetti code haha :D but I just need it to work till tomorrow, and then I have another 4 weeks to refactor and optimize. So I will just do it that way till tomorrow and then refactor with your input, thanks a lot for taking time to answer!